# Gradle build script doesn't perform curl command in cmd

Tags: groovy, build.gradle

I have gradle build script to test project build. Here I have a dependency with an external package which need to be downloaded and extracted if it is not already installed in the system.

Following is my script code in `build.gradle` to perform that task. But, it seems that the download is not performed as I don't see the downloaded files inside my build directory.

```
task checkBallerinaDist(type: Exec) {
    def fileName = "ballerina-${ballerinaLangVersion}-swan-lake"
    def downloadLink = "https://dist.ballerina.io/downloads/${ballerinaLangVersion}/${fileName}.zip"

    workingDir project.buildDir

    if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
        commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'bal', '--version'
    } else {
        commandLine 'bash', 'bal', '--version'
    }

    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ignoreExitValue = true

    doLast {
        String output = standardOutput.toString().trim()
        println "Ballerina distribution check result: $output"
        standardOutput = System.out

        if (executionResult.get().exitValue != 0 || !output.contains(ballerinaLangVersion)) {
            println "Ballerina distribution not found. Downloading..."

            if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'curl', '-o', fileName + '.zip', downloadLink, '--progress-bar'
                println "Curl command executed"
                println "Command line: ${commandLine}"
                println "Working directory: ${workingDir}"
                println "Exit value: ${executionResult.get().exitValue}"
                commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'tar', '-xf', fileName + '.zip'
                println "Tar command executed"
                println "Command line: ${commandLine}"
                println "Working directory: ${workingDir}"
                println "Exit value: ${executionResult.get().exitValue}"
            } else {
                // TODO: Handle this for Linux
            }

            System.setProperty("ballerina.home", "${project.buildDir}/${fileName}")
        } else {
            println "Ballerina distribution already exists"
            System.setProperty("ballerina.home", "${System.getenv("BALLERINA_HOME")}/distributions/ballerina-${ballerinaLangVersion}")
        }
    }
}

test {
    dependsOn checkBallerinaDist
    doFirst {
        println "Ballerina distribution path: ${System.getProperty("ballerina.home")}"
        systemProperties = [
                "target.dir"    : project.buildDir,
                "ballerina.home": System.getProperty("ballerina.home")
        ]
    }

    testLogging {
        showStackTraces = true
        showStandardStreams = true
    }

    useTestNG {
        suites "src/test/resources/testng.xml"
    }
    finalizedBy jacocoTestReport
}
```

Following is lines printed in console when gradle build is executed.

```
> Task :gateway-native:checkBallerinaDist
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
Ballerina distribution check result: Ballerina 2201.5.0 (Swan Lake Update 5)
Language specification 2022R4
Update Tool 1.3.14
Ballerina distribution not found. Downloading...
Curl command executed
Command line: [cmd, /c, curl, -o, ballerina-2201.6.0-swan-lake.zip, https://dist.ballerina.io/downloads/2201.6.0/ballerina-2201.6.0-swan-lake.zip, --progress-bar]
Working directory: D:\graphql-federation-gateway\native\build
Exit value: 0
Tar command executed
Command line: [cmd, /c, tar, -xf, ballerina-2201.6.0-swan-lake.zip]
Working directory: D:\graphql-federation-gateway\native\build
Exit value: 0

> Task :gateway-native:test
Ballerina distribution path: D:\graphql-federation-gateway\native\build/ballerina-2201.6.0-swan-lake
```

What is wrong with my script?.

Comment: My guess would be the wrong use of `/c` here. Either use `commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "curl -o ${fileName}.zip $downloadLink --progress-bar"` (everything as one argument, but make sure to quote things now according to the rules of the windows shell) or even better just call curl directly (remove the `'cmd', '/c'`).  Also are you sure, that your "windows tar" can deal with ZIP files?

Comment: @cfrick I tried all the possible solutions you suggested. Nothing got worked. Yes windows 11 cmd can handle `tar`. Any ways I got these done with an alternative way.
Downloaded using `de.undercouch.download` plugin. Thank you